# Настроить работу touchstart в js для ipad

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, события

пишу сайт под ipad. Для реализации нужно было отключить скролл страницы (показ должен идти только слайдами). Я пытался отлавливать события touchstart, touchend, click и прочие возможные для скроллинга, и в chrome (в режиме совместимости с ipad) всё работает - т.е. ничего не скроллится. Но с настоящего ipad события не перехватываются вообще. JS включен - простые alert'ы работают. Читал, что можно заменить событие тача на клик, но это мне не помогло. Не помогло обертывание блоков в ссылки. Не помогло выставление cursor:pointer. Не понимаю в чем дело. На android всё работает отлично. Код много (реально много), так что ниже приведу куски.

```
if (window.addEventListener) // старший FF
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);

window.addEventListener('wheel', preventDefault, {passive: false}); // современный стандарт
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', preventDefault, {passive: false}); // старые браузеры, IE
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', preventDefault, {passive: false}); // старые браузеры, IE

window.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStartHandler, {passive: false}); // мобилки (начало нажатия)
window.addEventListener('touchend', touchEndHandler, {passive: false}); // мобилки (конец нажатия)

document.onkeydown = preventDefaultForScrollKeys; // для клавиш
document.addEventListener('mousedown', preventDefaultForMidMouse); // для скм
```

Так вот ничего из этого не работает на ipad. На android и на винде в хроме - всё на ура. В чем может быть дело?